# Excel Conditional Formatting with 2 conditions across more than 1 sheet

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, conditional-formatting

I have a very simple setup:

Sheet 1

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 56.00% | 56.00% | 87.00% |  | 76.00% |

Sheet 2

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 |

What I want is to have all cells in Sheet1 in columns A through C whose value is less than Column E turn Red ONLY IF the corresponding cell in Sheet 2 is greater than 0.

So, the expected result would be that only Cell B1 would turn red.

I am using this formula: =AND($A$1 < $E$1,Sheet2!$A$1 >0) applies to =$A$1:$C$1

But it doesn't work (none of the cells change color).

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an absolute reference for `E1` but no other cells

```
=AND(A1 < $E$1,Sheet2!A1 >0)
```

Should work

(with your current conditions, the condition would apply to all cells if `Sheet2!A1` was greater than zero)